# Would this LiPo 3.7v -> 3.3v schematic be feasible?

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, battery-operated, lipo, schematic

I'm basing part of my design off of another schematic. It powers an ESP32, which can pull up to around 300mA at WiFi spikes.

I am planning on using a LDO regulator to bring 3.7v LiPo voltage (then through a Schottky, so 3.5v after the drop) to 3.3v. There are different regulators which I can use to make this happen, but I am asking specifically about this design that was used in another project.

VBAT = 3.7v

D2 drop is around 0.2v

The AP1117-33 is what worries me, as it has a dropout voltage of around 0.8v at 400mA (from [this](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP1117_R21.pdf) datasheet)

I could see someone using an LDO with a dropout voltage < 200mV, which would reliably get 3.3v from 3.5v. The ESP32 can run on voltages below 3v, and I would prefer to stay above 2.7v to not cause unintended behavior.

How would using an AP1117 in this situation work? In practice does it work with less input voltage than the datasheet says, or is the design just wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think it is bad design. I would try to find a different LDO if I were designing it. The graph shows more like 1V at 400 mA at 25 C. D2 just makes it that much worse.

Comment: You need something with a lower dropout than the 1117; that thing's from when 1.5ish volts was considered low dropout. An LDO may still be the best tool for the job, but also consider a buck-boost regulator; that would let your device work down to the discharge limit of the battery. With such low input-output differential though, a low-Iq LDO would probably be more efficient than a switching regulator.

Comment: You should begin by thinking about the range of voltages you will get from your battery, from its fully charged condition to the low voltage where the battery is considered "discharged".

Comment: Does this system use a voltage divider and ADC to sense battery voltage? And if so, what is the reference for the ADC?